# Android: Adding text from textView to status bar

Tags: java, android, textview, statusbar

Is it possible to add the String taken from textView to Status Bar. I want to show text constantly , dynamically updated as textView from apps main activity.

```
TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
message.setText("This I want to add to status bar");
```

Comment: I mean that notification bar, which is always top of the screen

Comment: So you want to use a notification?

Comment: Yes, but I just need to display variable next to clock.

Comment: Did you found how to add text to notification bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_status;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name); // Here you can pass the value of your TextView
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this way, everything is fine, but I  also want add value of variable next to icon, on that regular up bar.

Comment: use the above method, and get the String of the textview and pass it to the above method.

Comment: yes, but i want to display it all the time, not for a one second. its called the ticker text or something like this

Answer (score 1):

TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
message.setText("This I want to add to status bar");

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTittle(message.getText().toString());

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to show text from textview to status bar, you have to create [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification) And here is the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html) on how to update notification text at runtime.