# Create icon for notification on runtime

Tags: android

I want to show Internet Speed on status bar. Like this image

[image: Rendom icon on status bar].

For that reason i need lot of icon. I think this is not a good solution. Is any way to do `dynamic icon` on runtime.

Comment: Its not icon its textview in the notification you can setText on textview and displays as it is in image

Comment: Seriously bro. :O . It's two line with different  size !. If you doing this can you please share this code.

Comment: you can give custom layous for your notfications you need 2 textviews one below other ,dont have a ready code check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610598/android-adding-text-from-textview-to-status-bar