# How to add a text to android status bar using C++/QML

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, android-statusbar

I am trying to add some text to the android status bar using QT. I have a `main.qml` file that I will use to send the text to be written to the status bar of an android device.

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: So what is your question/ where is your problem? Or do you hope that someone is writing the `writeTextToStatusBar` for your ?

Comment: Question updated @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Comment: How do you want to add text to the status bar on android? I've never seen text in android status bar for my whole experience using android, only color and icons. Maybe, you need to use notifications?

Comment: Have you considered using your app in fullscreen mode and creating your won statusbar there? Because I am pretty sure its not possible to display text in the android statusbar

Comment: It is possible [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610598/android-adding-text-from-textview-to-status-bar) @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII